# Editable JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

If the user select the item which its index is 1,and change it from"123" to "abcd".how can I set "abcd" instead of "123" (in NetBeans)? Also how can I delete the item for ever?

Comment: What do you mean by set "abcd". Do you want to change the value in your model? If so, what model do you use?

Comment: I mean I want to change "123" to "abcd",for ever.
also I use Default model and with setEditable(true) I make it as an editable ComboBox

Comment: Given that you don't read suggestions given in your other postings it would seem to be a waste of time to make a suggestion in this posting.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. When the user changes a value AND presses [ENTER], the old value is removed and the new one is added.

If you need to replace the value at the same position, you will have to provide your own model that supports adding values at a certain position.

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Red", "Green", "Blue"});

comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private int selectedIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
        if(index >= 0) {
            selectedIndex = index;
        }
        else if("comboBoxEdited".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            Object newValue = model.getSelectedItem();
            model.removeElementAt(selectedIndex);
            model.addElement(newValue);
            comboBox.setSelectedItem(newValue);
            selectedIndex = model.getIndexOf(newValue);
        }
    }
});
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Nice! but with your code ,I can delete one item not more than that,why??

Comment: You are allowed to debug the code yourself to see what happening!

Comment: Not sure when you want to delete the row...
If you want to delete it when the user clears the input, check for that before re-adding the element

Comment: Thank you! Also note that the selected index when it is edited is `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorial [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

[image: Editable combo box, before and after the arrow button is clicked]

<sub>Editable combo box, before and after
the arrow button is clicked</sub>

See the :  *Using an Editable Combo Box* section.

Snippet from that page:

```
JComboBox patternList = new JComboBox(patternExamples);
patternList.setEditable(true);
patternList.addActionListener(this);
```